# Error when trying to download a file from database using linkbutton of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file from database using linkbutton of a gridview, but nothing is happening niether its giving me an error nor the file is bieng downloaded.
Here are my entities:

I have 3coulmns in my database- SaleID & SaleFilename(this coulmn stores files & their names), SaleName(This column Stores the same files in bytes)

Here is by .aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SaleName" SortExpression="SaleName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SaleFileName") %>' Text='<%# Bind("SaleName") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is my Code Behind File:

```
 protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
      // make sure fileName  contains only file name like 'test.pdf'  
            string fileName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

            // make sure filePath  contains file path like 'Uploads/Scheme/test.pdf' 

             string filePath = e.CommandArgument.ToString();


            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
            // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            byte[] bytes;
            //string ContentType;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select SaleFileName from Sales";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleFileName", SaleFileName );
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        bytes = (byte[])sdr["SaleFileName"];

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;

            // Read the original file from disk
             FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream( filePath  ,FileMode.Open);
            long FileSize = myFileStream.Length;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(FileSize)];
            myFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FileSize));
            myFileStream.Close();




           // // Tell the browse stuff about the file
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.ToString());
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & fileName.Replace(" ", "_"));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
            Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            // Send the data to the browser
            Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Web page is not giving me any response when we click the linkbutton to download the file, I am new to C# is anybody can tell me where I am making a mistake that would be a great help.

Comment: Is e.CommandName "Download" or 'SaleName"?

Comment: CommanName is Download

Comment: But the LinkButton you are showing is not, is it?

Comment: Yes CommandName is Download.

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel !?

Comment: No I am not using any update panel.